# SQLAlchemy-Flask Bind not working - NameError: name 'TABLE' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm looking to use Flask-SQLAlchemy Bind to connect to a secondary Oracle database.  I'm getting an error that says the table I want to connect to is not defined although it is defined in my model with the appropriate bind configuration added.   Here is the specific error:  NameError: name 'ACCOUNT' is not defined . This error happens before any attempt to actually query the database.

What am I missing?

I've browsed various examples via Google and StackOverflow and compared them with my code, but I do not see anything out of the ordinary with setup.

Here are the relevant bits of code... mysql queries work, oracle queries do not.

init.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

database_url = "mysql+pymysql://root:xxxx@localhost:3306/db1"
dbbind_url = "oracle://dbuser:xxxx@10.0.0.1:1521/db2" 

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_url
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_BINDS"] = {
    'oracle': dbbind_url
     }
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False 

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

models.py

```
## Mysql Model (working)
class CUSTOMERS (db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
## Oracle Model (not working)
class ACCOUNT(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ACCOUNT'
    __bind_key__ = 'oracle'
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    account = db.Column(db.String(400), nullable=False)
```

views.py

```
 @app.route('/helper', methods=['GET','POST'])
 def helper_search():

 form = HelperSearchForm()

 if form.validate_on_submit():

     accountquery = form.account.data
     print (accountquery)
     accountInfo = ACCOUNT.query.filter_by(ACCOUNT=accountquery).first()

 return redirect(url_for('helper_accountdetail',account=accountInfo))
```

"CUSTOMERS" Table Structure (MYSQL)

```
 id              INT     11
 name            VARCHAR 255
```

"ACCOUNT" Table Structure (Oracle)

```
 ACCOUNT_ID      NUMBER(11,0)   
 ACCOUNT         VARCHAR2(400 BYTE)
```

The current result is:
     NameError: name 'ACCOUNT' is not defined

The expected result is:
     The query is returned with a result.

Comment: Could you show `imports` in `views.py`?

Comment: well that's embarassing.  that was the problem.  I didn't declare ACCOUNT when importing app.models.